# h5 video poster stretched before play with chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video

there is a problem with chrome and android webview video player，the player object-fit attribute is set contain, however everything is well but when the video is ready to play a flash appear and the poster is stretched, is any way to fix it.